# jQuery onclick does not change HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I click the zero button, I expect the the function zero to change the input to zero, but it seems to be not working. Is there anyway to do this in JavaScript instead of jQuery?

### HTML

```
<div class="display" id="out">test</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in"></input>
</div>
<button id="zero" onclick="setzero()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Zero
</button>
```

### jQuery

```
$('#in').on("change", function(){
    $('#out').html($(this).val());
});

function setzero() {
  $('#in').val(0);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ahpu8wwx/12/

Comment: Check [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ahpu8wwx/16/), you need to select `no wrap` option

Answer (score 0):

> The `onlick` is not working because the the function `setzero()` is not in global context so you need to move it outside the document ready handler

You can use **[`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)** event handler and trigger change event using **[`cahnge()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)**

```js
$('#in').on("change", function() {
  $('#out').html($(this).val());
});
$('#zero').click(function() {
  $('#in').val(0).change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display" id="out">test</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in">
</div>
<button id="zero">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Zero
</button>
```

**Update :** Or you need to define the function outside the `$(document).ready(function(){..});` handler

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#in').on("change", function() {
    $('#out').html($(this).val());
  });
});


function setzero() {
  $('#in').val(0).change();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display" id="out">test</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="comment">value:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0.00" id="in">
</div>
<button id="zero" onclick="setzero(this)">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Zero
</button>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it in JavaScript rather than jQuery?

Comment: As @Tushar said in comment you need to put the function outside the document ready handler http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ahpu8wwx/16/

Comment: But choosing the no wrap option makes the  'change' function in jQuery not working?

Comment: yea, but if you click the Zero button, the input value goes to 0 but the output doesn't change...

Comment: Thank you. You are amazing.

Comment: @user75521 : glad to help

Answer (score 0):

try you updated I have updated adding a new variable sum

```
var sum = 0;
$('#in').on("change", function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
    $('#out').html(sum);
    setzero();
});

function setzero() {
  $('#in').val(0);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/muhammadusmaann/ahpu8wwx/18/)

Answer (score 0):

**Tushar** needs to put his comment to the answer:

You code is correct, but you run it in a wrong context in fiddle, you need to set "No Wrap" option like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use jquery events, using it for the click is working

```
$('#zero').on('click', function(e){
    $('#in').val(0);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```